# How to deal with mutual inclusions in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, require, circular-dependency

I'm developing a Node.js application that contains a game engine, and I basically have this pattern in my engine:

**A.js**

```
var B = require('./B');

var A = module.exports = function () {
    this.b = new B;

    console.log(B.staticBar)
};

A.staticFoo = 'foo';
```

**B.js**

```
var A = require('./A');

var B = module.exports = function () {
    console.log(A.staticFoo);
};

B.staticBar = 'bar';
```

So I want both A.staticFoo to be accessible in B.js and B.staticBar in A.js.
Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

EDIT : actually my static variables are config values, so another solution would be to group them into a **config.js** file and require that file in every other file, but I find it more elegant to define config variables directly as static members of related classes. Hope that's clear enough ;)

Comment: Don't you need to do `var B = require('./B');` to access B? Otherwise the module will be executed, but not imported.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest separating your static state into a third module... By decoupling state from your module, you can operate either independently.

### state.js

```
//state.js - changed by other modules...
module.exports = {
  staticFoo: null,
  staticBar: null
};
```

### a.js

```
//a.js
var state = require('./state');
exports = module.exports = fnA;
...
function fnA() {
  console.log(state.staticBar);
}
```

### b.js

```
//b.js
var state = require('./state');
exports = module.exports = fnB;
...
function fnB() {
  console.log(state.staticFoo);
}
```

---

Another example mentions something akin to dependency injection... given how modules work in JS, and that you can override for testing with proxyquire and the like, I tend to prefer the simpler requires structure over dealing with DI/IoC in JS as it muddles your project code.

I also like to do my requires, then my exports, then any methods within that module, usually just one method in a module.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the architecture of your code.  BUT, working with other people's code is always different of course.

The *best* choice is to separate your code into smaller module(s).  If they're referencing each other it can challenging to build tests especially when the code grows.

OR

If that's not possible you could always remove coupling through the use of references.

**B.js**

```
var _A;
exports.setA = function(ref) {
  _A = ref;
};

var B = exports.B = function () {
    console.log(_A.staticFoo);
};
```

And use `B.setA(A)` to make sure `B` has a reference to use `A.staticFoo`